# I keep getting the error "canvasContext.fillRect" in this following code

Tags: javascript, canvas

Every time I run the app and open the console this error "pong.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: canvasContext.fillRect is not a function at drawEverything (pong.js:25)" keeps coming up every second, at first I thought it was because I didn't spell "fillRect" properly, but I cannot figure out why this is happening, any ideas? Thanks

```js
var canvas
var canvasContext;
var ballX = 50;



window.onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
    //get context to draw on 
    canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

   setInterval(drawEverything, 1000);




}


function drawEverything() {
    ballX = ballX + 20;

    console.log(ballX);
    canvasContext.fillStyle = 'black';
    canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    canvasContext.fillRect = 'white';
    canvasContext.fillRect(225,210,200,200);
    canvasContext.fillStyle = 'red';
    canvasContext.fillRect(ballX, 200, 50, 25);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your are overriding your fillRect function with string

```
canvasContext.fillRect = 'white';
```